# PreferenceFragment is empty (Android)

Tags: android, android-preferences

When I launch the app nothing shows on screen

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXW50.png)

I tried to extend PreferenceActivity instead of AppCompactActivity, but it didn't work.

The code in MainActivity is

```
package com.hamza.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.general_prefs);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

}
```

The code inside xml/generel_prefs.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:entries="@array/unit_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/unit_entry_values"
        android:key="unit"
        android:title="Unit" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="Zip Code"
        android:key="zipcode"
        android:defaultValue="72345"
        />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

and the code in values/array.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="unit_entries">
        <item>Metric</item>
        <item>Imperial</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="unit_entry_values">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Thanks

Comment: your MainActivity doesn't setContentView()?

Comment: @MinFu later. I added setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but it didn't work.

Comment: btw you call addPreferencesFromResource before super.onCreate. This will give you a `java.lang.RuntimeException: This should be called after super.onCreate.`

Answer (score 4):

I used

the wrong onCreate method
I used this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

instead of this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```